# How to set up AWS EC2 for multiple node.js apps?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchdb

I'm experimenting with switching from PaaS (nodejitsu) to IaaS (AWS). I'd like to make use of node.js, couchdb, express, npm, git and websockets. Now here's the tricky part. I'd like to be able to update my apps without downtime, and I'd like to be able to update node and couchdb without downtime. Any ideas? Have any of the node.js PaaSs open sourced their software?

I know I'm asking for a lot here, any help at all would rock!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run more than one app on one instance of EC2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549026/how-to-run-more-than-one-app-on-one-instance-of-ec2)

Answer (score 1):

If you combine Nginx with your Node.js application server then you can achieve zero downtime restarts of your application.

More info at [Zero Downtime Deployments with Nginx](http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-3-zero-downtime-deployments-with-nginx/).